# accuracy of pow vs repeated multiplications in c

Tags: c, gcc, floating-point

I have some floating point code that under code profiling gets bogged down in repeated calls to pow. Since the number of values that is being powered is very limited, and the exponents can be factored to be all integers, I want to replace these calls with pre-computed arrays.

Code performance wise, pre-computing the arrays is unlikely to be very significant, however what are the **accuracy** implications of :

```
array[0]= 1 ;
for (int n=1 ; n<100 ; n++)
    array[n]=array[n-1]*some_double ;
```

vs

```
for (int n=0 ; n<100 ; n++)
    array[n]=pow(some_double , n) ;
```

assume n does not exceed 100, probably less. Answers for long double also appreciated if different.

Comment: Have you tested this? I would imagine the outputs are quite similar.

Comment: Code up both versions and compare the results.

Comment: and just how is one supposed to do that for an arbitrary double? without missing an edge case? I was hoping the spec might say something that I am missing, particularly given pow specked to be 1ulp and a multiply 0.5ulp, naively this is telling me that optimially first 4 values should be multiplies,  and thereafter use pow. I am far from convinced however.

Comment: What are you going to do with these powers? If you are going to evaluate polynomials, you might want to consider horner's method (eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method) instead

Comment: FYI: Note the way to implement exponentiation with minimal multiplications is not the squaring method but [addition-chain exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition-chain_exponentiation).

Comment: @EricPostpischil So you get a couple less multiplications than binary exponentiation for the low, low cost of a NP-complete problem determining the shortest addition-chain for the desired exponent. Seems great!

Comment: @EOF: The chains can be precomputed, and they only need to be precomputed once to be used for any number of multiplicands.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So if you want to compute `pow(variable, constant)` for several different values of `variable` that would save time? A bit like `variable/constant` is optimized to `variable*inverse(constant)` (mostly for integer division) by decent compilers? Seems a bit niche, though probably very useful for *some* workloads.

Comment: @EOF: The question specifically asks about the accuracy of alternative computations. It is in bold.

Comment: @EricPostpischil And your comment is about minimizing the *number* of multiplications. I would expect the error to mostly be affected by the depth of the multiplication expression tree, does addition-chain-exponentiation *actually* reduce the error compared to binary exponentiation?

Comment: @EOF: Each multiplication introduces a rounding error. Due to the nature of fixed-width floating-point formats, they are essentially additive when measured as relative errors, and they are reasonably well modeled as a uniform distribution from −½ to +½ except for special multiplicands (e.g., low powers of multiplicands with just a few significant bits to start with, such as 2 or 1.375, in contrast to 1.3). So the cumulative error approaches a normal distribution whose width depends on the number of multiplications.

Comment: @EricPostpischil is what what you are saying is that if we multiply 100 times, we would expect a normally distributed error of sqrt(50)bits so about 7 bits, unfortunately even 2 standard deviations brings us to 14 extra bits needed to still encompass only 95% of cases - way beyond the extra precision of long double, and still no guarantees, so one would need to use _float128. It seems that the options are addition chain, use the pow function, or exponentiate a precomputed log (cuts the overhead of the pow function and just does what it seems to fall back on as far as I can see from the source)

Answer (score 3):

This should give you a vague idea:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double mypow(double d, int n)
{
  double result = d;
  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    result *= d;

  return result;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  for (double d = 0; d < 10; d += 0.1)
  {
    for (int n = 1; n < 100; n++)
    {
      double r1 = pow(d, n);
      double r2 = mypow(d, n);    
      printf("d = %f, n = %d %f %f %f\n", d,n,r1, r2, r1-r2);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your consecutive multiplications lead to 100 rounding errors being added up. You can do that in more clever ways: Store x^0 and x^1, then use x^(2n) = (x^n)^2, and x^(2n+1) = x^(2n) * x. Much less build-up on rounding errors.

Now compare to pow(x, n): A good library implementation will realise that n is an integer and calculate the result using multiplications, and it will use the same multiplications that my code above did, *or it will do something more clever*. A more clever implementation would use long double for the intermediate results, or would use quad precision arithmetic to get the results with the smallest possible rounding errors.

Since you only calculate 100 powers, if you are really interested in keeping the rounding error as low as possible, I'd be tempted to use pow().

Answer (score 1):

> code profiling gets bogged down in repeated calls to pow.

To improve overall speed performance, rather than look how to do x<sup>y</sup> faster, post the larger code.  Best optimizations involve a wider view of code.

---

`*` vs. `pow()` performance.

Repeated multications `*` incur up to 1/2 [ULP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place) in the product each time.  With 10<sup>100</sup> that is 99 multiplications and an error of √99 * 0.5 ULP can be expected.

The compiler, depending on `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` may use wider math for `*` and result in negligible error.

`pow()` is a tricky library function to implement well.  The error in z = x<sup>y</sup> with simplistic implementations is proportional to ln(|z|) (IIRC) - this is quite bad for large z.  A good `pow()` will use extended math and other crafted code to minimize the error, potentially down to 1.0 ULP.  This comes at a modest time performance cost.

For a quality answer, use `pow()` unless raising to a simplistic small integer power like 2,3,4.

---

Some alternative code for `double` raise to an positive integer power.  More time efficient than a loop of multiplications once `n` is maybe 5 or more.  Likely more accurate.

```
double pow_n(double base, unsigned exp) {
  double y = 1.0;
  while (1) {
    if (exp % 2) y *= base;
    exp /= 2;
    if (exp == 0) break;  
    base *= base;
  }
  return y;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know there is no circuit to calculate Exponentiation, which means that the pow() function must be an algorithm (can't be done by hardware at single clock cycle). There are many papers about this and the main concern is precision and not performance (each time you do a multiplication you lose precision) some algorithms compensate after each multiplication and this will require more computation.
My assumptions is not about your case, in worst case scenario the algorithm for pow() will be the same as doing it manually, but taking into account all CPUs, operating systems and compilers.

```
//this should be faster
array[0]= 1 ;
for (int n=1 ; n<100 ; n++)
array[n]=array[n-1]*some_double ;

//this should be more accurate 
for (int n=0 ; n<100 ; n++)
    array[n]=pow(some_double , n) ;
```